# What is the verb to say "negatively affect" in terms of temporary impairment done to intelligence or ability?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been searching for a verb that acurately means "negatively affect", especially when it's used to describe a situation where a person's intellectual capacity is temporarily harmed or damaged, causing failure in performance or functioning.
For example, a drunk person's judgement is temporarily *negatively affected* due to the alcohol.

I have looked up words like "hamper", "hinder", "impede". But none of their definitions match the meaning I want to express.

But I don't mean "retarded" or "decreased intellectual capacity". Because I want a more general and abstract word to describe "causing a restriction to a person's ability to function physically, mentally, or socially."

Can you help me with this question?

Comment: Why not look up the verb related to _impairment_?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The logical verb if you want to talk about impairment is "[impair](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/impair)"

Comment: Thank you very much! I look up the definition of "impair" through the link you attach, and I find the definiton exactly matches what I want to express! I guess I just understand impair as "damage" not "negatively affect" before. Very helpful.

Comment: @Bradley If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//english.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

**mar**

> to damage or spoil to a certain extent; render less perfect, attractive, useful, etc.; impair or spoil

*That billboard mars the view.*

*The holiday was marred by bad weather.*

[Dictionary.com]